# C# project minimum references set

Tags: c#, project

I have a class library project in C# that just references the `System` assembly; it compiles fine, but obviously cannot be used on its own as it is just a class library.

The projects that use that library have a greater number of referenced assemblies. In particular, they all seem to include `System.Core` and `Microsoft.CSharp`, among others. All the projects work fine right now, but I cant help but wonder if it just works because the library's needed DLLs are a subset of those by the enclosing project, or because .NET assemblies are in the GAC and are magically found when required transitively.

What is the minimum acceptable reference set assuming a hello world program (i.e. no linq, no xml, no configuration, etc.)?

Should the library project also reference `System.Core` and `Microsoft.CSharp` explicitly? These sound pretty important.

=====

`EDIT:` The class library project template in Visual Studio always includes `System.Core` and `Microsoft.CSharp` by default, even though removing them always seems to be OK. This is why I'm wondering if they are being referenced implicitly.

Comment: "A hello world project"?  Such a project is implied to output "hello world" somehow.  Your minimum set of references is going to be different depending on how you output "hello world", be it to the console, via a dialog box, saved to a file, sent down the wire, printed on a printer...

Comment: No. If those dlls (System.Core and Microsoft.CSharp) are not required then no need to reference them.

Comment: Simply remove all references. You'll see, what doesn't compile and for that you need to add references again. The simplest program does not have any obvious reference, but includes (implicitely) mscorlib.dll. Also you can double-click the reference to see what's inside (or use Reflector)

Comment: You get those references from the project template.  There is very little point in worrying about it, the compiler removes references when they are not used.

Comment: @cvraman: Thanks. I wonder why Microsoft decided to include those by default in the project template.

Comment: @JeffRson yes, I always do that, that's how my question arised; I was wondering why I can always seem to remove them with no apparent negative effect. My class library compiles fine without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the minimum acceptable reference set assuming a hello world program

This one:

```
// HelloWorld.cs
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
}
```

will depend only from mscorlib. Compile it this way:

> csc.exe HelloWorld.cs

Answer (score 2):

The minimum library you need is `mscorlib.dll` (and it is a must have reference) for a small console application limited to basic input and output operation. basic IO operations & threading.

Besides that, mscorlib.dll has .Net Framework's most basic things (implementation). You should have a look at mscorlib.dll using application like `Reflector` or `dotPeek`.

Comment: @JeffRSon - that is why i am saying it is a must have reference that is implicitly included by the compiler, one can skip referencing to mscorlib.dll with `/nostdlib`

Comment: @AppDeveloper: have you tried to compile something with `nostdlib` option? :)

Comment: So it is possible to have a console app with no references ?

Comment: @cvraman - minimal one dll is a must, besides every other dll except mscorlib references to it, so it will be loaded by the .Net runtime.

Comment: @cvraman: in fact no, it's impossible. `nostdlib`, AFAIK, is intended to compile `mscorlib` itself.

Comment: @cvraman - you are right, it is intended to compile mscorlib itself :P

Comment: @AppDeveloper : Well I found that I was able to create a basic console app in VS2010 with no references. I was curious as to how functions like Console.WriteLine were being loaded :D

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm, marking the other answer as I think it's slightly more succinct and well presented, but I learned a lot from these comments.